# Seleccionar fecha de inicio y fin de un calendario usando python con selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Soy nuevo usando selenium, he instentado usando xpath pero se generan mas calendarios con sus fechas y no puedo detectar el dia en cuestion quiesiera alguna ayuda para resolver este problema.En el codigo primero selecciono el calendaario,me desplazo con las dos flechas un año mas y trato de seleccionar el diapara la fecha inicio, para la fecha final igual.

[image: Calendario]

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ftriggercc4"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="button nav"]//div[@unselectable="on"][normalize-space()="»"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
diainicial = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class,'day')and normalize-space()='5']").click()
time.sleep(5)
diafinal = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ftriggercc6"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="button nav"]//div[@unselectable="on"][normalize-space()="»"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
diainicial = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class,'day')and normalize-space()='31']").click()

Comment: podrías explicar un poco mas el detalle a la pregunta?
, lo que entiendo es que deseas cambiar la fecha o algo por el estilo

Comment: Hola  MrDonPh0x si lo que quiero es cambiar la fecha de inicio que esta en un calendario y fecha fin en otro.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar la fecha de inicio y fin de un calendario usando Python con Selenium, primero necesitarías tener una instancia de la clase WebDriver de Selenium para controlar el navegador web y acceder al sitio web que contiene el calendario.

Una vez que tengas una instancia de WebDriver, puedes usar el método find_element_by_css_selector para encontrar el elemento del calendario en la página web y hacer clic en él para abrirlo. Luego, puedes seleccionar la fecha de inicio y fin usando los métodos send_keys y send_return para enviar las fechas seleccionadas al calendario y confirmar la selección.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de código que muestra cómo seleccionar la fecha de inicio y fin de un calendario usando Python con Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Crea una instancia de la clase WebDriver para controlar el navegador web
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Accede al sitio web que contiene el calendario
driver.get('http://ejemplo.com/calendario')

# Encuentra el elemento del calendario en la página web y hace clic en él para abrirlo
calendar_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#calendario')
calendar_element.click()

# Selecciona la fecha de inicio y fin enviando las fechas seleccionadas al calendario y confirmandola
```